# Java - returning object arbitrarily that repeats more then one

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a class that relies on three classes I have created before.
I have a method in the 4th class, in which I was requested to get the newest `Car` object.
If there is more, from one such, one of them will be returned arbitrarily.
The method called `getNewest()`

Posting the current class and the one before it to reference for you to make the connection:

Previous 3rd class -> Car

```
public class Car {

private  Owner _owner; //an object from 1st class
private String _manufacturer;
private boolean _airbag;
private boolean _leasingOrRental;
private int _km, _seats, _year;
private int _price;
private int _LevyPrice;
private Bid _highestBid;//an object from 2st class

public Car(Owner ow, String mfr, boolean isAirbag, boolean leasOrRent, int kilNum, int seatNum, int date, int price, int levy, Bid high) // Constructor
{
    _owner = new Owner(ow);
    _manufacturer = mfr;
    _airbag = isAirbag;
    _leasingOrRental = leasOrRent;
    _km = kilNum;
    _seats = seatNum;
    _year = date;
    _price = price;
    _LevyPrice = levy;
    _highestBid = new Bid(high);
}

public Car(Car other) //copy constrcutor 
{
    _owner = new Owner(other._owner);
    _manufacturer = other._manufacturer;
    _airbag = other._airbag;
    _leasingOrRental = other._leasingOrRental;;
    _km = other._km;
    _seats = other._seats;;
    _year = other._year;
    _price = other._price;
    _LevyPrice = other._LevyPrice;
    _highestBid = new Bid(other._highestBid); 
}

public Owner getOwner()
{
    return new Owner(_owner);
}

public String getManufacturer()
{
    return _manufacturer;
}

public boolean getAirbag()
{
    return _airbag;
}

public boolean getIsleasingOrRental()
{
    return _leasingOrRental;
}

public int getKm() {
    return _km;
}

public int getSeats() {
    return _seats;
}

public int getYear() {
    return _year;
}

public int getLevyPrice() {
    return _LevyPrice;
}

public Bid getHighestBid() {
    return new Bid(_highestBid);
}

public void makeBid(Bid bid)
{
    if (_highestBid.getBidPrice() < bid.getBidPrice())
        _highestBid.setBidPrice(bid.getBidPrice());
}

public boolean isAttractive()
{
    return _airbag == true && _leasingOrRental == true && (_km > 0 && _km < 20000 ) && _year >= 3;
}

public boolean fitForFamily(int kids)
{
    return _seats - 2 >= kids;
}

public boolean overUsedCar()
{
    final int KILOMERTES = 12000;

    return _km > KILOMERTES*(2022 - _year);
}

public String toString()
{
    return "Manufacturer: "+_manufacturer+"\n"
            +"Year: "+_year+"\n"
            +"Owner: "+_owner.toString()+"\n"
            +"Highest bid: "+_highestBid.getBidPrice();
}
```

}

4th and current class `CarSales` with

```
public class CarSales {

private Car[] _cars;
int _noOfCars;

public CarSales(int size)
{
    _cars = new Car[size];
    _noOfCars = 0;
}

public boolean addCar(Car car)
{
    int size = _cars.length+1;
    //_cars = new Car[_noOfCars];
    if(_cars.length < _noOfCars)
    {
        _cars[size] = new Car(car);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public Car getNewest()
{
    Car newest = _cars[0];
    Car [] _new = new Car[_noOfCars];
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < _cars.length; i++)
        if(newest.getYear() < _cars[i].getYear())
            newest = _cars[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < _cars.length; i++)
        if (newest.getYear() == _cars[i].getYear())
            size++;

    for (int i = 0; i < _cars.length; i++)
        if (newest.getYear() == _cars[i].getYear())
            _new[i] = new Car(_cars[i]);

    return _new[0];
}
}
```

In my method I created, I'm returning the first object, but I can return it after the first loop if I'm doing this that way from the start.
But I want to make the option to return the object arbitrarily if I have more than one object.
Also, if there is a way to make it more efficient, I would appreciate your example.

Cannot use `ArrayList` lang like add or copy or indexOf must be done logically.

Thanks in advance for all helpers and feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the constructor of class `CarSales`, you initialize `_cars`. Here is the relevant line from the code in your question.

```java
_cars = new Car[size];
```

This creates an array of `size` elements but every element is null. Hence the purpose of `_noOfCars` is to tell you how many non-null elements are in the array `_cars`. Therefore, in all the `for` loops in method `getNewest` (in class `CarSales`) you need to iterate through all the non-null elements of array `_cars` rather than through all the elements. Hence each `for` loop should be:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < _noOfCars; i++)
```

Consequently, method `addCar` (also in class `CarSales`) needs to update `_noOfCars`. Here is the corrected method.

```
public boolean addCar(Car car) {
    if (_noOfCars < _cars.length) {
        _cars[_noOfCars++] = car;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I assume that in method `getNewest` you want to return a random element from the array containing all the newest cars. In the below code, I use class [ThreadLocalRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) to generate a random index for the array.

```
public Car getNewest() {
    Car newest = _cars[0];
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < _noOfCars; i++)
        if (newest.getYear() < _cars[i].getYear())
            newest = _cars[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < _noOfCars; i++)
        if (newest.getYear() == _cars[i].getYear())
            size++;

    Car[] _new = new Car[size];
    int ndx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < _noOfCars; i++)
        if (newest.getYear() == _cars[i].getYear())
            _new[ndx++] = new Car(_cars[i]);

    return _new[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, _new.length)];
}
```

Here is a complete example. Since you didn't post the code for classes `Owner` and `Bid`, I made up minimal definitions for them and I also added a `main` method to class `Car` so as to get a complete program that can be compiled and run.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Car {
    private Owner _owner; // an object from 1st class
    private String _manufacturer;
    private boolean _airbag;
    private boolean _leasingOrRental;
    private int _km, _seats, _year;
    private int _price;
    private int _LevyPrice;
    private Bid _highestBid;// an object from 2st class

    // Constructor
    public Car(Owner ow,
               String mfr,
               boolean isAirbag,
               boolean leasOrRent,
               int kilNum,
               int seatNum,
               int date,
               int price,
               int levy,
               Bid high) {
        _owner = ow; // new Owner(ow);
        _manufacturer = mfr;
        _airbag = isAirbag;
        _leasingOrRental = leasOrRent;
        _km = kilNum;
        _seats = seatNum;
        _year = date;
        _price = price;
        _LevyPrice = levy;
        _highestBid = high; // new Bid(high);
    }

    // copy constrcutor
    public Car(Car other) {
        _owner = other._owner; // new Owner(other._owner);
        _manufacturer = other._manufacturer;
        _airbag = other._airbag;
        _leasingOrRental = other._leasingOrRental;
        _km = other._km;
        _seats = other._seats;
        _year = other._year;
        _price = other._price;
        _LevyPrice = other._LevyPrice;
        _highestBid = other._highestBid; // new Bid(other._highestBid);
    }

    public Owner getOwner() {
        return _owner; // new Owner(_owner);
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return _manufacturer;
    }

    public boolean getAirbag() {
        return _airbag;
    }

    public boolean getIsleasingOrRental() {
        return _leasingOrRental;
    }

    public int getKm() {
        return _km;
    }

    public int getSeats() {
        return _seats;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return _year;
    }

    public int getLevyPrice() {
        return _LevyPrice;
    }

    public Bid getHighestBid() {
        return _highestBid; // new Bid(_highestBid);
    }

    public void makeBid(Bid bid) {
        if (_highestBid.getBidPrice() < bid.getBidPrice())
            _highestBid.setBidPrice(bid.getBidPrice());
    }

    public boolean isAttractive() {
        return _airbag == true && _leasingOrRental == true && (_km > 0 && _km < 20000)
                && _year >= 3;
    }

    public boolean fitForFamily(int kids) {
        return _seats - 2 >= kids;
    }

    public boolean overUsedCar() {
        final int KILOMERTES = 12000;

        return _km > KILOMERTES * (2022 - _year);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Manufacturer: " + _manufacturer + "\n" + "Year: " + _year + "\n" + "Owner: "
                + _owner.toString() + "\n" + "Highest bid: " + _highestBid.getBidPrice();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CarSales carSales = new CarSales(5);
        Car carOne = new Car(new Owner("George"), "mfr", true, true, 0, 5, 2020, 1, 1, new Bid(2));
        carSales.addCar(carOne);
        Car carTwo = new Car(new Owner("May"), "mfr", true, true, 0, 5, 2020, 2, 2, new Bid(4));
        carSales.addCar(carTwo);
        System.out.println(carSales.getNewest());
    }
}

class CarSales {
    private Car[] _cars;
    private int _noOfCars;

    public CarSales(int size) {
        _cars = new Car[size];
        _noOfCars = 0;
    }

    public boolean addCar(Car car) {
        if (_noOfCars < _cars.length) {
            _cars[_noOfCars++] = car;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Car getNewest() {
        Car newest = _cars[0];
        int size = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < _noOfCars; i++)
            if (newest.getYear() < _cars[i].getYear())
                newest = _cars[i];

        for (int i = 0; i < _noOfCars; i++)
            if (newest.getYear() == _cars[i].getYear())
                size++;

        Car[] _new = new Car[size];
        int ndx = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < _noOfCars; i++)
            if (newest.getYear() == _cars[i].getYear())
                _new[ndx++] = new Car(_cars[i]);

        return _new[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, _new.length)];
    }
}

class Bid {
    private double bidPrice;

    public Bid(double price) {
        bidPrice = price;
    }

    public double getBidPrice() {
        return bidPrice;
    }

    public void setBidPrice(double bidPrice) {
        this.bidPrice = bidPrice;
    }
}

class Owner {
    private String name;

    public Owner(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Abra!! i must tell you that you got my head straight. really really helped me your exmaples, and explanations.